# what's the difference between "important to" and "important for"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When do we use *important for* and *important to*? What's the rule?
For example:

> It's important to me.

Or

> It's important for me.

What's the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: Breathing is important ***to*** me because it is important ***for*** me!

Comment: *"It's important **for** him to like me"* would usually be taken as meaning it matters ***to me*** that he should like me. But *"It's important **to** him to like me"* can only ever mean ***he*** cares a lot or has a lot to gain by liking me.

Comment: _Important to `Person`_ is an emotional judgement of person `P`. _Important for `X`_ is a conclusion about a chain of causation resulting in `X`.

Comment: If I want to find out more about situations like this, what should I look for? Important is an adjective in this case.. do adjectives have prepositions? What is the name of that relationship?

Answer (score 9):

*Important to* signifies a connection to the specified subject (in this case *me*). *Important for* denotes importance for a certain *cause*.

*It's important to me!* refers to something you value or hold in great esteem.

*It's important for me!* refers to a cause, e.g. *It's important for my health/success* etc.

Answer (score 7):

"X is important to Y" where "Y" is a conscious entity denotes that Y values X.

> My parents are important to me.

"X is important for Y" denotes that X is something that Y really needs or that Y will be severely affected by not having X. In this case "Y" does not have to be a conscious entity.

> Sunlight is important for plant growth.
>
> Water is important for survival.